# Jquery Modal popup error message overlay

Tags: php

I am using jquery tooltipster for showing error messages.
Here if I open any modal pop up means that message will over lay the screen.
How to solve it? Can any one help?

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXMk3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuqrf.png)

Comment: Incomplete Ques.Please share what you've been upto

Comment: this is more of a css question. the issue lies with your divs and modal width:

Comment: true, this is wrong tag. and the image shows kinda messed up html output, you shall inspect source -> are all div correctly closed where they should be ?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but No Friend i am not getting solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix `z-index` of your tooltip message. Assuming the tooltip message div/span has a class `tooltip`:

```
.tooltip{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1151 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but No Friend i am not getting solution!!!

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct tooltip class. Inspect element on Google Chrome and check if this CSS is added to the element.